# Search through all my database tables - MySQL, JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, database, select

I am building one big application on Java. The problem I faced is that I have to search for a particular string in all database. I know in which column it should be but it could  be in all tables.
Here it is:

> I have 10 tables with the same columns and structure. One of them is storing ID of the product. I have search field in my Java application so the mySQL string behind this search needs to dig in all database (all ID columns of the tables).

Basically it has to look something like this:

```
Select *
from *.[database-name]

where [the particular column].*.[database] is lke %?%
```

I know code looks awful but it is only example to get the idea. I am sure that it is something about information_schema but I really cannot remember how and also cannot find answers as well(that satisfied me) in the site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider using UNION  or UNION ALL to have one result and then make select from there

Comment: Also if you are `building one big application on Java` consider make only one table not 10 tables that are the same.

Comment: That option was considered and rejected by client

Comment: Since you know which (10) tables to search and which column might contain the ID I see no point in involving information_schema in this, UNION (ALL) like mentioned above with a select for each table seems like the best solution

Comment: _I have 10 tables with the same columns and structure._ Does tend to indicatce a Database Design mistake

Comment: Joakim you are right, it would be easy BUT i was not max accurate in description. Client wants every time when he decide to buy new material (1material=1table) to be created new table. So I am ready with that but he also wants this new table to be involve in search. So to sum up, I won't be sure how many tables should be involved.

Comment: splitting table horizontally usually comes with an ID generation strategy. For example,  ID in Table1 starts with 1. find the strategy and route it in your JAVA code.